# Where are the dimensions of products in a woocommerce order stored?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The problem: we sell products in bulk they are large and weigh a lot, usually shipped on pallets.

The plugins for calculating shipping, often err as summarized all the products in one pile, where the largest item at the bottom and up to infinity.

I want a courier service plugin to get pallet dimensions, I have an algorithm for how to calculate pallet dimensions, but I don't understand what array is used for calculations within woocommerce to replace it?

For example: 100 apples in an array for packaging, I will replace it with one pallet and already it will be counted by the shipping plugin.

Takes data from

- the product individually `$product`
- cart `WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages()`

Or from somewhere else?